# PANDAS: Puedo rellenar valores NAN en solo una columna de mi dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un `dataframe` de 3 columnas todas numericas. Dentro de los datos hay valores faltantes `NAN` y no tengo problemas en rellenarlos con `fillna(method=pad)` todas menos los `NAN` de la primera columna que requiero `fillna(mean())`. Hay una manera de rellenar los `NAN` por columna para usar metodos distintos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De esta forma proceso el nan en la primera columna.

```
df.time =df.time.fillna(df.time.mean())
```

De esta forma proceso los nan del resto de las columnas.

```
df[['gold','silver']] = df[['gold','silver']].fillna(method='pad')
```

Encontre la solucion >:)